# Values on the x-axis overlapping in ggvis plots on Shiny

Tags: shiny, ggvis, shinydashboard

I am using Shinydashboard environment to display ggvis plots.
I want to have 3 of them in a line so I used something like that (the plots are not exactly similar to the ones I actually used but they produce a similar effect) :

```
ui.R

fluidRow(
column(4,ggvisOutput("plot1")),
column(4,ggvisOutput("plot2")),
column(4,ggvisOutput("plot3")))  


server.R
vis<-reactive({
mtcars %>% ggvis(~1000*mpg,~wt,fill=~vs)%>%layer_points()%>%
set_options(width = 'auto', height = 400) })
vis %>%bind_shiny("plot1")
```

However due to the plots being compressed by each other, the values on the x-axis on each plot are overlapping each other, which makes the reading of every graph impossible.

[image]

Do you know if there is a way to force ggvis to automatically scale the x-axis to make it readable ? Do I also have to play on the width by adjusting the width in pixels. Do you know of another way (on Shiny maybe) ?

Comment: I found that you could use: add_axis("x",values=seq(0,max(1000*df$mpg),by=max(1000*df$mpg)/5))
to have only 5 subdivisions. However it is more of a work around than of a real fix

Comment: And still it is overlapping...

Comment: I add subdivide=9 to the options but still I do not quite like my solution

Comment: You could set the number of ticks via, e.g., `ticks = 5`.  You could also change the orientation of the tick labels for a better fit with `properties = axis_props(labels = list(angle = 45, align = "left"))` to see if that scales better.  This may lead you to setting a bigger axis title offset via `title_offset` and changing the tick padding via `tick_padding`.

Comment: Ticks is better yes, but still it does not feel totally right